# Is it possible to encrypt a PDF using a certificate with Adobe Livecycle ES2?

Tags: encryption, adobe, rsa, livecycle

I want to use RSA keys to encrypt PDF documents. I use Adobe Livecycle ES2 for that. The [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/9.0/programLC/help/index.htm?content=000819.html) talks about decrypting the encrypted document with a public key. That means it is not encrypted, but signed by the author. I want to achieve that only one user can open the document, which means I have to encrypt it with the public key of that user and he has to decrypt it with his private key.

Is that possible with Adobe Livecycle ES2? Can I just use his private key, instead of my private key? Or does it make a difference to LC?

Comment: It looks like it may be a typo in the documentation tbh. Save that one public/private mismatch it looks like it does what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are referring to the statement "*After the PDF document is encrypted, you need the corresponding public key to decrypt it.*" under the heading "**Create a certificate-encrypted PDF document**". As Bruno mentioned, it is a typo. It should read "corresponding private key". The certificate contains only the public key.

Comment: Thank you very much for that answer. It totally solves my problem so far.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Look here for an instruction how to do it.

http://forums.adobe.com/message/3592521#3592521